# How to prohibit access to dependencies of a dependency

Tags: java, maven, module, dependencies

I am currently experimenting with maven module structures.
At the moment I have the following structure:

```
A -> B -> C
```

where A depends on B and B depends on C and A,B,C are separate maven modules.

Is it somehow possible for B to mask its dependency on C so that A can not directly call public functions or instantiate objects from C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mark B's dependency on C as [`<optional>true</optional>`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html). This will prevent Maven from resolving this dependency transitively, so A will not transitively depend on C. This means that when A is built, it will not have C on its classpath at all, unless A defines explicit dependency on C.

Naturally, if A defines an explicit dependency on C, Maven will add it. Maven is a build tool, not a security framework that can prevent A from ever accessing C explicitly.

Also, `<scope>provided<scope>` has a different meaning, but works similarly in regards to transitive dependencies.

Comment: You're welcome. However, please do read documentation about this feature. Using this might imply you're not structuring your projects correctly. Perhaps a more "Maveny" approach would be to split B into two parts: the part that requires C (B1) and the part that doesn't (B2). A and B1 would then simply both depend on B2.

Comment: I just noticed that if A gets an object of an interface (in B) which is actually an instance of a class from C constructed in a factory (also in B), there will be a ClassNotFoundException

Comment: Indeed, if A wants to use classes from C, it needs to have C on classpath. I cannot be very precise with so little detail about what kind of environment you're working with.
Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, perhaps the following structure could work for you: B-api (the B2 above), B-impl (B1 with dependency on C), A-library (requires B, symbolized by dependency on B-api), D-application (depends on A-library and B-impl for the library). Then you build D as the final application, it'll have everything on classpath. But when developing A, it'll use api, not impl.